# Redirect unzip output to particular directory using Perl

Tags: perl, unzip

I want to uncompress zipped file say, `files.zip`, to a directory that is different from my working directory. 
Say, my working directory is `/home/user/address` and I want to unzip files in `/home/user/name`.

I am trying to do it as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $files= "/home/user/name/files.zip"; #location of zip file
my $wd = "/home/user/address" #working directory
my $newdir= "/home/user/name"; #directory where files need to be extracted
my $dir = `cd $newdir`;
my @result = `unzip $files`;
```

But when run the above from my working directory, all the files get unzipped in working directory. How do I redirect the uncompressed files to `$newdir`?

Comment: If you want to change your working directory take a look at the chdir function http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html

Comment: This question was not Perl related at all. In fact, it is not a programming question at all. It is a question about command line options to `unzip` which you can find out by just typing <kbd>unzip</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the command line.

Comment: @Sinan: It is Perl related as I also wanted to know what command in Perl changes the directory. As mentioned by mobrule, it is chdir. I would not have come to know this if it was not for him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
unzip $files -d $newdir
```

Comment: You don't need `man`. Just type `unzip` on the command line and press `Enter`.

Comment: @Sinan: his question is what -d does and where to get more info

Answer (score 3):

Use Perl command

```
chdir $newdir;
```

and not the backticks

```
`cd $newdir`
```

which will just start a new shell, change the directory in that shell, and then exit.

Answer (score 1):

Though for this example, the -d option to unzip is probably the simplest way to do what you want (as mentioned by ennuikiller), for other types of directory-changing, I like the File::chdir module, which allows you to localize directory changes, when combined with the perl "local" operator:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::chdir;

my $files= "/home/user/name/files.zip"; #location of zip file
my $wd = "/home/user/address" #working directory
my $newdir= "/home/user/name"; #directory where files need to be extracted
# doesn't work, since cd is inside a subshell:   my $dir = `cd $newdir`;
{ 
   local $CWD = $newdir;
   # Within this block, the current working directory is $newdir
   my @result = `unzip $files`;
}
# here the current working directory is back to what it was before
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Archive::Zip module. Look specifically at the extractToFileNamed:

"extractToFileNamed( $fileName )

Extract me to a file with the given name. The file will be created with default modes. Directories will be created as needed. The $fileName argument should be a valid file name on your file system. Returns AZ_OK on success. "